# How to find the area of a trapezium with unequal non parallel sides?

Tags: geometry

A carpenter has cut a board in the shape of trapezium. If the parallel sides of the trapezium are 28 cm and 25 cm, and non parallel sides are 25 cm and 26 cm, find the area of the board.

Comment: have you made an Image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let the perpendicular of the given trapezium $h$ and $x$ and $y$ are the legs of the right triangles, then $$x+y=3$$ and $$(3-x)^2+h^2=26^2$$ and $$x^2+h^2=25^2$$
can you solve this?
and we get
$$(3-\sqrt{25^2-h^2})^2+h^2=26^2$$ this equation must you solve for $h$

Comment: I'm quite confused. I think I can't get the height because the non parallel sides are unequal. Please enlighten me.

Comment: we can get the hight

Comment: How? Please enlighten me sir

Comment: Can we still have parallel lines with this dimensions?

Comment: let us say the other non parallel side is $$26$$ so we have

Comment: $$x^2+h^2=26^2$$ and $$y^2+h^2=25^2$$ then we have $$(3-\sqrt{26^2-h^2})^2+h^2=25^2$$

Comment: solving this for $h$ we get $$h=\sqrt{26^2-10^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

HINTS

[image]

By similar triangles ( sketch not to proportion)

$$ \dfrac{x}{x+25}= \dfrac{y}{y+26}= \dfrac{25}{28}, \,(=R\, say) $$

Compute $x,y$

Compute area of big triangle ( 3 sides known, use Brahmagupta/Heron)  and multiply it by $ (1-R^2) $ for trapezium area.

Comment: Thank you. But what's the basis of multiplying it by (1-R^2) to get the trapezium area? I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: The small area to big one is in proportion of ratio $R$ linearly (sides etc.) and area ratio is $R^2$. And so remaining trapezium  part is $ (1-R^2) $